# Showing the signal generated on Heikin Ashi candlesticks on normal candlesticks

Tags: pine-script

I think this indicator gives better results on heikin ashi candlesticks.
But I want to follow the relevant commodity in normal candlesticks.
I want it to show the signals produced in the heikin ashi while tracking on normal candlesticks.

I did research and tests, but I could not reach a successful result.

```
study("Trend_Test", overlay = true, format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")

Periods = input(title="ATR Period", type=input.integer, defval=10)
src = input(hl2, title="Source")
Multiplier = input(title="ATR Multiplier", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=3.0)
changeATR= input(title="Change ATR Calculation Method ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
showsignals = input(title="Show Buy/Sell Signals ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
highlighting = input(title="Highlighter On/Off ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
atr2 = sma(tr, Periods)
atr= changeATR ? atr(Periods) : atr2
up=src-(Multiplier*atr)
up1 = nz(up[1],up)
up := close[1] > up1 ? max(up,up1) : up
dn=src+(Multiplier*atr)
dn1 = nz(dn[1], dn)
dn := close[1] < dn1 ? min(dn, dn1) : dn
trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], trend)
trend := trend == -1 and close > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < up1 ? -1 : trend
upPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? up : na, title="Up Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.green)
buySignal = trend == 1 and trend[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal ? up : na, title="UpTrend Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, transp=0)
plotshape(buySignal and showsignals ? up : na, title="Buy", text="Buy", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
dnPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? na : dn, title="Down Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.red)
sellSignal = trend == -1 and trend[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal ? dn : na, title="DownTrend Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, transp=0)
plotshape(sellSignal and showsignals ? dn : na, title="Sell", text="Sell", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
mPlot = plot(ohlc4, title="", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0)
longFillColor = highlighting ? (trend == 1 ? color.green : color.white) : color.white
shortFillColor = highlighting ? (trend == -1 ? color.red : color.white) : color.white
fill(mPlot, upPlot, title="UpTrend Highligter", color=longFillColor)
fill(mPlot, dnPlot, title="DownTrend Highligter", color=shortFillColor)
alertcondition(buySignal, title="Buy", message="SuperTrend Buy!")
alertcondition(sellSignal, title="Sell", message="SuperTrend Sell!")
changeCond = trend != trend[1]
alertcondition(changeCond, title="Trend Direction Change", message="SuperTrend has changed direction!")
```

Answer (score 1):

This means you need to calculate your indicator based on the values from HA, this can be done on the main chart using the security() function, where the heikinashi() function should be the result of the ticker. Code example:

```
//@version=4
study("Trend_Test", overlay = true, format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")

[o,h,l,c]=security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, [open, high, low, close]) // request ohlc from HA chart

Periods = input(title="ATR Period", type=input.integer, defval=10)
src = (h+l)/2 // Custom series can't be used as inputs, so use our own hl2 of HA without input() func
Multiplier = input(title="ATR Multiplier", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=3.0)
changeATR= input(title="Change ATR Calculation Method ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
showsignals = input(title="Show Buy/Sell Signals ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
hlighting = input(title="Highlighter On/Off ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
trHa = max(h - l, abs(h - c[1]), abs(l - c[1])) // calculate HA true range
atr2 = sma(trHa, Periods) // SMA of HA tr
atr= changeATR ? rma(trHa, Periods) : atr2 // atr calcs on main ohlc, so use rma() of HA true range for HA atr calculation 
up=src-(Multiplier*atr)
up1 = nz(up[1],up)
up := c[1] > up1 ? max(up,up1) : up
dn=src+(Multiplier*atr)
dn1 = nz(dn[1], dn)
dn := c[1] < dn1 ? min(dn, dn1) : dn
trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], trend)
trend := trend == -1 and c > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and c < up1 ? -1 : trend
upPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? up : na, title="Up Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.green)
buySignal = trend == 1 and trend[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal ? up : na, title="UpTrend Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, transp=0)
plotshape(buySignal and showsignals ? up : na, title="Buy", text="Buy", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
dnPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? na : dn, title="Down Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.red)
sellSignal = trend == -1 and trend[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal ? dn : na, title="DownTrend Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, transp=0)
plotshape(sellSignal and showsignals ? dn : na, title="Sell", text="Sell", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
mPlot = plot((o+h+l+c)/4, title="", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0) // use HA ohlc4
longFillColor = hlighting ? (trend == 1 ? color.green : color.white) : color.white
shortFillColor = hlighting ? (trend == -1 ? color.red : color.white) : color.white
fill(mPlot, upPlot, title="UpTrend hligter", color=longFillColor)
fill(mPlot, dnPlot, title="DownTrend hligter", color=shortFillColor)
alertcondition(buySignal, title="Buy", message="SuperTrend Buy!")
alertcondition(sellSignal, title="Sell", message="SuperTrend Sell!")
changeCond = trend != trend[1]
alertcondition(changeCond, title="Trend Direction Change", message="SuperTrend has changed direction!")
```

There is a more elegant and correct way to do this. It is necessary to extract the calculation code into a function. And pass this function to the expression argument of the security with HA ticker. The code will become more readable and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="partial exits ", overlay=true )

heikinashi_close = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close)

heikinashi_aapl_60_close = request.security(ticker.heikinashi("banknifty"),  "60", close)

plot(heikinashi_close)
plot(heikinashi_aapl_60_close)
```

Comment: you can read in pine v5 manual

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).