# Unable to change Pine Script Strategy from Candle to hakinashi in code but not in calulation of strategy

Tags: pine-script

I would like to calculate my strategy in hakanshi candles but keep the view in normal candles. I found the following:

[Showing the signal generated on Heikin Ashi candlesticks on normal candlesticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70515528/showing-the-signal-generated-on-heikin-ashi-candlesticks-on-normal-candlesticks)

And I adapt my code from:

```
//@version=4
// Copyright (c) 2019-present, Alex Orekhov (everget)
// Chandelier Exit script may be freely distributed under the terms of the GPL-3.0 license.
strategy("Chandelier Exit", shorttitle="SOL", overlay=true, initial_capital=1000, slippage=7)

lengthBuy = input(title="ATR Sell", type=input.integer, defval=1)
lengthSell = input(title="ATR Buy", type=input.integer, defval=2)
multBuy = input(title="ATR Mult. Sell", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=8.0)
multSell = input(title="ATR Mult. Buy", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=5.7)
showLabels = input(title="Show Buy/Sell Labels ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
useCloseBuy = input(title="Sell: Use Close Price for Extremums ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
useCloseSell = input(title="Buy: Use Close Price for Extremums ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
highlightState = input(title="Highlight State ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
//SUM = input(title="Capital", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=1000)


//Berechne Anzahl Coins
//currentBalance = strategy.initial_capital + strategy.netprofit
//AmountC = (currentBalance / close[1])/2

currentBalance = strategy.initial_capital + strategy.netprofit
AmountC = (currentBalance / close[1])

// Make input options that configure backtest date range
startDate = input(title="Start Date", type=input.integer,
     defval=1, minval=1, maxval=31)
startMonth = input(title="Start Month", type=input.integer,
     defval=6, minval=1, maxval=12)
startYear = input(title="Start Year", type=input.integer,
     defval=2022, minval=1800, maxval=2100)

endDate = input(title="End Date", type=input.integer,
     defval=31, minval=1, maxval=31)
endMonth = input(title="End Month", type=input.integer,
     defval=6, minval=1, maxval=12)
endYear = input(title="End Year", type=input.integer,
     defval=2022, minval=1800, maxval=2100)

atrBuy = multBuy * atr(lengthBuy)
atrSell = multSell * atr(lengthSell)


longStop = (useCloseBuy ? highest(close, lengthBuy) : highest(lengthBuy)) - atrBuy
longStopPrev = nz(longStop[1], longStop) 
longStop := close[1] > longStopPrev ? max(longStop, longStopPrev) : longStop

shortStop = (useCloseSell ? lowest(close, lengthSell) : lowest(lengthSell)) + atrSell
shortStopPrev = nz(shortStop[1], shortStop)
shortStop := close[1] < shortStopPrev ? min(shortStop, shortStopPrev) : shortStop

var int dir = 1
dir := close > shortStopPrev ? 1 : close < longStopPrev ? -1 : dir

var color longColor = color.green
var color shortColor = color.red


buySignal = dir == 1 and dir[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal and showLabels ? longStop : na, title="Buy Label", text="Buy", location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=longColor, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)


sellSignal = dir == -1 and dir[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal and showLabels ? shortStop : na, title="Sell Label", text="Sell", location=location.abovebar, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=shortColor, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)

midPricePlot = plot(ohlc4, title="", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0, display=display.none, editable=false)

// Look if the close time of the current bar
// falls inside the date range
inDateRange = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, startYear,
         startMonth, startDate, 0, 0)) and
     (time < timestamp(syminfo.timezone, endYear, endMonth, endDate, 0, 0))
     
if (inDateRange and buySignal)
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, AmountC)
    
//strategy.exit("ExitLong", from_entry="buy", loss=150)
    
//if (inDateRange and sellSignal)
   // strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short, AmountC)
    
if (inDateRange and sellSignal)
    strategy.close("buy")    


changeCond = dir != dir[1]
alertcondition(changeCond, title="Alert: CE Direction Change", message="Chandelier Exit has changed direction!")
alertcondition(buySignal, title="Alert: CE Buy", message="Chandelier Exit Buy!")
alertcondition(sellSignal, title="Alert: CE Sell", message="Chandelier Exit Sell!")
```

to the following code:

```
//@version=4
// Copyright (c) 2019-present, Alex Orekhov (everget)
// Chandelier Exit script may be freely distributed under the terms of the GPL-3.0 license.
strategy("Chandelier Exit", shorttitle="SOL", overlay=true, initial_capital=1000, slippage=7)

lengthBuy = input(title="ATR Sell", type=input.integer, defval=1)
lengthSell = input(title="ATR Buy", type=input.integer, defval=2)
multBuy = input(title="ATR Mult. Sell", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=8.0)
multSell = input(title="ATR Mult. Buy", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=5.7)
showLabels = input(title="Show Buy/Sell Labels ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
useCloseBuy = input(title="Sell: Use Close Price for Extremums ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
useCloseSell = input(title="Buy: Use Close Price for Extremums ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
highlightState = input(title="Highlight State ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
//SUM = input(title="Capital", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=1000)


//Berechne Anzahl Coins
//currentBalance = strategy.initial_capital + strategy.netprofit
//AmountC = (currentBalance / close[1])/2

currentBalance = strategy.initial_capital + strategy.netprofit
AmountC = (currentBalance / close[1])

// Make input options that configure backtest date range
startDate = input(title="Start Date", type=input.integer,
     defval=1, minval=1, maxval=31)
startMonth = input(title="Start Month", type=input.integer,
     defval=6, minval=1, maxval=12)
startYear = input(title="Start Year", type=input.integer,
     defval=2022, minval=1800, maxval=2100)

endDate = input(title="End Date", type=input.integer,
     defval=31, minval=1, maxval=31)
endMonth = input(title="End Month", type=input.integer,
     defval=6, minval=1, maxval=12)
endYear = input(title="End Year", type=input.integer,
     defval=2022, minval=1800, maxval=2100)

[o,h,l,c]=security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, [open, high, low, close]) // request ohlc from HA chart


atrBuy = multBuy * atr(lengthBuy)
atrSell = multSell * atr(lengthSell)


longStop = (useCloseBuy ? highest(c, lengthBuy) : highest(lengthBuy)) - atrBuy
longStopPrev = nz(longStop[1], longStop) 
longStop := c[1] > longStopPrev ? max(longStop, longStopPrev) : longStop

shortStop = (useCloseSell ? lowest(c, lengthSell) : lowest(lengthSell)) + atrSell
shortStopPrev = nz(shortStop[1], shortStop)
shortStop := c[1] < shortStopPrev ? min(shortStop, shortStopPrev) : shortStop

var int dir = 1
dir := c > shortStopPrev ? 1 : c < longStopPrev ? -1 : dir

var color longColor = color.green
var color shortColor = color.red


buySignal = dir == 1 and dir[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal and showLabels ? longStop : na, title="Buy Label", text="Buy", location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=longColor, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)


sellSignal = dir == -1 and dir[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal and showLabels ? shortStop : na, title="Sell Label", text="Sell", location=location.abovebar, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=shortColor, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)

midPricePlot = plot(ohlc4, title="", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0, display=display.none, editable=false)

// Look if the close time of the current bar
// falls inside the date range
inDateRange = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, startYear,
         startMonth, startDate, 0, 0)) and
     (time < timestamp(syminfo.timezone, endYear, endMonth, endDate, 0, 0))
     
if (inDateRange and buySignal)
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, AmountC)
    
//strategy.exit("ExitLong", from_entry="buy", loss=150)
    
//if (inDateRange and sellSignal)
   // strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short, AmountC)
    
if (inDateRange and sellSignal)
    strategy.close("buy")    


changeCond = dir != dir[1]
alertcondition(changeCond, title="Alert: CE Direction Change", message="Chandelier Exit has changed direction!")
alertcondition(buySignal, title="Alert: CE Buy", message="Chandelier Exit Buy!")
alertcondition(sellSignal, title="Alert: CE Sell", message="Chandelier Exit Sell!")
```

But if I switch veiws in tradingview between candles and hakinashi alsow the output changes. Were is my mistake?
I am new to pine script and didn't find a solution so thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have not read the entire updated code but the below line you are using close of normal candle instead of HA candle. Please correct and the update the question

```
AmountC = (currentBalance / close[1])
```